# While loop creating multiply variables with counter

Tags: bash, variables, unix, while-loop

```
#!/bin/bash

n=1
while (( $n <= 5 ))
do
  num$n=`echo "$n"`
  n=$(( n+1 ))

done
echo "$num1"
```

ok so what I am trying to do is create a while loop that will create variables and just put something into it in this case its just the value of n but i cant get it to do this!

so basically it will create num1, num2, num3 and so on

```
echo "$num1"
echo "$num2"
echo "$num3"
```

should display

```
1
2
3
```

but i keep getting an error am i missing something here cause it shouldnt be anything crazy to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
#!/bin/bash

    n=1
    while (( $n <= 5 ))
    do
      eval num$n=`echo "$n"`
      n=$(( n+1 ))

    done
    echo "$num1"
    echo "$num2"
    echo "$num3"
```

The problem here is that bash is trying to evaluate num$n as a command, which does not exist, so the error.

Comment: Perfect i knew it was gonna be something small forgot all about eval awesome job!

Comment: so one last thing is there anyway to echo it inside the while loop like this eval echo "$num$n" to print the 1 2 3 etc?

Answer (score 0):

Don't dynamically create numbered variable names like this; use an array.

```
n=1
while (( $n <= 5 )); do
    nums[$n]=$n  # No need to execute $(echo ...)
    n=$((n+1))
done

echo "${num[1]}"
echo "${num[2]}"
echo "${num[3]}"
```

Comment: Is it wrong to dynamically create variables?? Or is it just better practice to use arrays?